# How to properly detach shared memory segments - segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory-management, hashtable, ipc, shared-memory

i am writing a program which creates and use a hash table and uses shared memory. My program works but sometimes it causes segmentation faults . I believe that i dont detach shared memory segments properly since its the first time i use it. *Should i detach segment* everytime i use it ? Thanks in advance for your help!

code :

```
#define SIZE 83000

int indexar = 0;
int shared = 0;

char Entries[SIZE][256];
char st_arr[SIZE][256];


int shmid;
char (*array)[SIZE][50];
int foo = 0;

void put(char *key, char *value ) {


  //item->uniq = uniq;
  int found = 0 ;


  shmid = shmget(123, SIZE * 50, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

  array = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

  strcpy(st_arr[indexar], key);



  if (foo == 0 ) { /* shared memory initialized once */

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
      strcpy((*array)[i], "0");
    }
    foo = 1;

  }



  for (int i = 0; i < indexar ; i++ ) {

    if (!strcmp(st_arr[i], key)) {

      found = found + 1;

    }
  }


  //get the hash
  unsigned long hashIndex = get_hashed(key, found);

  //move in array until an empty or deleted cell
  while ((strcmp((*array)[hashIndex], "0") && (strcmp((*array)[hashIndex + 1], "0")))) {
    //go to next cell
    hashIndex = hashIndex + 2;

    //wrap around the table
    hashIndex %= SIZE;
  }

  //strcpy(Entries[hashIndex],key);
  //strcpy(Entries[hashIndex+1],value);



  //printf("%d shmid\n",shmid );

  //char (*array)[SIZE][50];
  //shmid = shmget(123, SIZE * 50, IPC_CREAT | 0666); //for shared memory
  //array = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);

  printf("%d\n", hashIndex );
  strcpy((*array)[hashIndex], key);
  strcpy((*array)[hashIndex + 1], value);
  printf("\n[%d] = %s---\n", hashIndex, (*array)[hashIndex] );

  //shmdt((void *) array);

  indexar = indexar + 1;
  shared = shared + 2;
}


///////////////////////////////////////
char *get(char *key) {
  //get the hash
  int uniq = 0;
  unsigned long hashIndex = get_hashed(key, uniq) ;

  shmid = shmget(123, SIZE * 50, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

  array = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);


  //move in array until an empty
  while (strcmp((*array)[hashIndex], "0") && (hashIndex<SIZE))   {


    if (strncmp((*array)[hashIndex] , key, 4) == 0) {
      //printf("%lu \n",hashIndex);
      //shmdt((void *) array);
      return  (*array)[hashIndex + 1];


    }

    //go to next cell
    ++hashIndex;

    //wrap around the table
    hashIndex %= SIZE;

  }

  //printf("%lu \n", hashIndex);
  //shmdt((void *) array);
  return "not found";
}
```

**edit:** Code works , but it gives segmentation fault if i use put() function 4-5 times. Also variable array is declared as a global variable.

Comment: Can you add the declarations of your variables like `st_arr`, `array` etc.?

Comment: @mch yes i will edit

Comment: `while (strcmp((*array)[hashIndex], "0") && (hashIndex<SIZE))` is wrong, you should first check if the index is valid and then use it ==> `while ((hashIndex<SIZE) && strcmp((*array)[hashIndex], "0"))`.

Comment: @mch i didnt know that thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check `hashIndex` and `hashIndex + (value)` limit range. I mean at your complete implementation check if `hashIndex` or `hashIndex + (value)` exceeding limit ( e.g. `SIZE` )

Comment: I will double check it  although in my code i dont detach anywhere the shared memory segment (thats my main concern). Is it ok to do that?

Comment: If you allocate memory @runtime then you should make them free also immediately after going to out of scope.